# PInvoke for complex method calls C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using a 3. party SDK, which is made up from .dll, .lib and .h files.
I am using the .dll's to PInvoke against. And the .h files to see the function names and parameters. (So I am not using the .lib files).

The SDK is rather complex, so making the PInvoke wrappers have proven to be a challenge. All the functions/structs/enums is defined in the .h files.

The function I am trying to wrap is called InitBaseComponent, and I can call it, but it returns a "Error In Argument" enum back. So my guess is it is marshalling that creates this problem. 
So the question is: I am doing this right?

**Function: InitBaseComponent(...)**

```
//C Function: InitBaseComponent(...)
ERROR InitBaseComponent(
    Method_Interface* methodInterface, //[in]
    void* methodInst, //[in]
    ErrorCallBackFunction errorCallbackFunc, //[in]
    void* ErrorCallbackInst, //[in]
    Component* BaseComponent //[in, out]
);

//C# Function: InitBaseComponent(...)
[DllImport("externalSDK.dll", EntryPoint = "InitBaseComponent", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern ERROR InitBaseComponent(
    Method_Interface methodInterface, 
    IntPtr methodInst, 
    ErrorCallBackFunction errorCallbackFunc, 
    IntPtr ErrorCallbackInst, 
    out Component BaseComponent 
);
```

**Enum: ERROR**

```
//C Enum: ERROR 
typedef enum ERROR_E {
    OK = 0, //Everything is ok
    E_ARG = 1, //Error in the Arguments 
    E_DATA = 2 //Data error
    //And more...
 } ERROR;

 //C# Enum: ERROR
 public enum ERROR
 {
    OK = 0, //Everything is ok
    E_ARG = 1, //Error in the Arguments 
    E_DATA = 2 //Data error
    //And more...
 }
```

**Struct: Method_Interface**

```
//C struct: Method_Interface
typedef struct Method_Interface_S 
{
    void* (*Method1)(void* Inst, size_t size);
    void* (*Method2)(void* Inst, size_t nelements, size_t bytes);
    void* (*Method3)(void* Inst, void *pointer, size_t size);
    void (*Method4)(void* Inst, void* pointer);
}Method_Interface;

//C# class: Method_Interface
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class Method_Interface
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void Method1_delegate(IntPtr Inst, uint size);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void Method2_delegate(IntPtr Inst, uint nelements, uint bytes);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void Method3_delegate(IntPtr Inst, IntPtr pointer, uint size);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void Method4_delegate(IntPtr Inst, IntPtr pointer);

    public Method1_delegate Method1;
    public Method2_delegate Method2;
    public Method3_delegate Method3;
    public Method4_delegate Method4;
}
```

**Delegate: ErrorCallBackFunction**

```
//C ErrorCallBackFunction
typedef void (*ErrorCallBackFunction)(void* errorCallBackInst, ERROR errorCode, const char* szMessage, const char* szDetail);

//C# delegate: ErrorCallBackFunction
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void ErrorCallBackFunction(IntPtr errorCallBackInst, ERROR errorCode, string szMessage, string szDetail);
```

**Struct: Component**

```
//C struct: Component
typedef struct Component_S
{
    void* ObjPointer;    
    unsigned long number; 
} Component;

//C# class: Component
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class Component
{
    public IntPtr ObjPointer;
    public ulong number;
}
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `Component` in the C# as a class. That means that it is already a reference. But then you passed it as an `out` parameter which adds an extra layer of indirection, one too many. So, you need to remove the `out`, just as you did for `methodInterface`.

```
[DllImport(...)]
public static extern ERROR InitBaseComponent(
    Method_Interface methodInterface, 
    IntPtr methodInst, 
    ErrorCallBackFunction errorCallbackFunc, 
    IntPtr ErrorCallbackInst, 
    Component BaseComponent 
);
```

Obviously you need to instantiate the `Component` object in your C# before you call `InitBaseComponent`.

Some other observations:

1. `size_t` is pointer sized, so your translation as `uint` will fail on 64 bit platforms.
2. C# `long` is 64 bits, but C++ `long` is 32 bits, on Windows. So your translation of the C++ `Component` struct is wrong. The `number` field must be declared with type `uint`.

Comment: I have removed the "out". And I have tried to change all C size_t / C# uint to C size_t / C# IntPtr. And I have changed ulong number uint.  Sadly it didn't help.

Comment: But if I have a IntPtr(another function call which is to set a void*), I can set it to "out" and it is getting a value all nicely.

Comment: Do you think I got something wrong? What exactly do you disagree with? I suspect that you don't understand what the `out` is doing. That has the effect of telling the marshaller to pass a pointer to `BaseComponent`. Remove the `out` and you instead pass `BaseComponent`. So your `out` is putting an extra, erroneous, layer of indirection.

Comment: I'm wondering, do you fully understand the implication of declaring your struct translations as `class` rather than `struct`? It's fine to declare them as `class`, but it makes them a reference type rather than a value type. And so when you pass an instance of a class, you are passing a reference to the object, and the p/invoke turns that into a pointer. Essentially this boils down to the fact that in C# an instance variable is really just a pointer to the object.

Comment: Another way to think of this is as follows. When you pass a class by `out` or `ref` that means that you are asking the native code to modify the reference. Well, it can't very well do that. Only the managed code can synthesise new instances of a class. The only scenario where `out <someclasstype> instance` or `ref <someclasstype> instance` would be viable would be if the native code was already holding a list of possible references to managed objects that it could pick from. Or perhaps if the native code could make a call back to the managed code to get one.

Comment: I am not sure. The problem is it "doesn't work" (very usefull I know). When I call the function I do NOT get an exception saying it doesn't match the signature or anything. So I do call the function, but it have some internal sanity checks for the input i provide, and one or more of these sanity checks fails (it doesn't say which). The idea for this function is to set up the "Component object". And I am not sure what goes wrong

Comment: So, in summary, the use of `out Component` where `Component` is a class is a giant indicator of a problem.

Comment: Did you instantiate the `Component` instance like I said? Before you call the function? I note that you did not show how you call the function. Have you even made the code changes that I described?

Comment: The Component is inistatiated before the call yes. And I have removed the "out" from the function so it looks like this:    [DllImport("externalSDK.dll", EntryPoint = "InitBaseComponent", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern ERROR InitBaseComponent(
Method_Interface methodInterface, 
IntPtr methodInst, 
ErrorCallBackFunction errorCallbackFunc, 
IntPtr ErrorCallbackInst, 
Component BaseComponent 
); (Cannot format my comments, sorry)

Comment: Well, I imagine that the parameters that you pass are wrong. The interop is fine now. I don't have the docs of the library and I don't want to get into that. I believe I answered the question that you asked. I think your problem is now unrelated to the code in the question.

Comment: The docs of the library that you don't really want to get into well... The docs specifies that the Component have to be instantiated by specific null type the SDK provides (which it does) Component component = SDKPinvoke.GetNullComponent(); When I look at it in C# the  Component is inistantiated to null.

Comment: That cannot be right. You have to make one like this `Component component = new Component()` or however the syntax goes. You cannot pass `null` in that parameter. How can the native code fill it out if you pass a null pointer. The native code expects a pointer to `struct Component_S`. You still did not show how you make the call. I rolled the question back since there seems little point repeating my answer there.

Comment: From the docs for the Component BaseComponent: "Filled by the API with an initialized Base component. The application must intialize the component with the null component see GetNullComponent()"

Comment: What is the value of the component that you pass? Is it `null`?

Comment: What I do is: Component component = SDKPinvoke.GetNullComponent(); ERROR er = SDKPinvoke.InitBaseComponent(....,component); And the component is null at this time, yes.

Comment: OK. That's the problem. Clearly if you pass `null` in the final parameter then it will fail. You cannot hope to call `GetNullComponent()`. Remember that `Component` is a C# class. It's impossible for the native code to make a new one. You could possibly make this fly if you switched to using struct rather than `class`. If you did that then you'd need to pass the structs by `ref`.

Comment: Now, I think that I answered the question that you asked. Your problem might not yet be fully solved, but I've answered what you asked. I don't want to debug the rest of this in comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41632/discussion-between-mr-java-wolf-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: next steps: 1. Convert two classes to structs. 2. Change params to ref. 3. Hope the call to GetNullComponent() works out!

Comment: GetNullComponent() returns a nice stuct now

Comment: But I get other "related problems"... That does take a bit more to explain.